# Extract emails from a list of url

Tags: php, regex

I have a list of urls that I want to extract the email or from the href or from the text. Each page has one email only.

The problem is that my list is big and can not do it manually.

```
<a href="mailto:EMAIL" class="spamspan">EMAIL</a>
```

How can I do this using PHP, regex?

Comment: [Don't use regexes for parsing HTML](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454)

Comment: @JohnConde is this a reason for downvoting though ?

Comment: No. But not showing any effort is.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/201323/using-a-regular-expression-to-validate-an-email-address

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
/mailto:([a-zA-Z0-9_\.-]+@[\da-z\.-]+\.[a-z\.]{2,6})"/gm
```

see this demo https://regex101.com/r/mC7jM3/1

Comment: Thank you but it seems that i can not get it from the actual page. I get this instead array(2) { [0]=> array(0) { } [1]=> array(0) { } }

Comment: Actually I tried to get this

`array(2) { [0]=> array(1) { [0]=> string(107) "name [at] domain [dot] com" } [1]=> array(1) { [0]=> string(54) "name [at] domain [dot] comr" } }` How can I output the `name [at] domain [dot] com` ?

Answer (score 1):

```
Extract  email from url contain 
<?php

  $the_url = isset($_REQUEST['url']) ? htmlspecialchars($_REQUEST['url']) : '';
  if (isset($_REQUEST['url']) && !empty($_REQUEST['url'])) {
      $text = file_get_contents($_REQUEST['url']);
  }
  elseif (isset($_REQUEST['text']) && !empty($_REQUEST['text'])) {
      $text = $_REQUEST['text'];
  }
  if (!empty($text)) {
      $res = preg_match_all(
           "/[a-z0-9]+([_\\.-][a-z0-9]+)*@([a-z0-9]+([\.-][a-z0-9]+)*)+\\.[a-z]{2,}/i", $text, $matches
      );
      if ($res) {
          foreach (array_unique($matches[0]) as $email) {
              echo  $email . "<br />";
    }
      }
      else {
          echo "No emails found.";
      }
  }

?>

<form method="post" action="">
    Please enter full URL of the page to parse (including http://):<br />
    <input type="text" name="url" size="65" value="<?php echo $the_url; ?>"/><br />
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

Comment: Thank You, sure it did work on google search result page too. Abhinondan